# Can I use cperl-mode with perl-mode colorization?

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

The Emacs cperl-mode seems to get confused less than perl-mode, but the Skittles effect makes the thing unusable for me.  Does anyone have or know of an example of a .emacs block that causes cperl-mode to use the colorization from perl-mode, ideally in a form readable enough that I can go back and turn back on the default colors one element at a time until I reach something I'm comfortable with?

In particular there is a hideously shade of light green used for some builtins that I find quite unreadable, and I prefer my variables to not have the leading `$` and `$$` and such tinted red along with the variable name.  Most of the rest are merely distracting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press M-x customize-group RET cperl-faces RET and change coloring to your liking.

Comment: This doesn't quite cover everything, like allowing me to prevent colorization of leading glyphs, but it looks like this is as close as I'm going to get, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With colour themes, the problem is limited to arrays and hashes - and it turns out that that's because cperl-mode defines those faces as being bold-weight, which colour themes don't appear to affect ([Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) doesn't).

In Emacs 23.3 on Mac OS, the following restored the colours to how the colour theme defined them:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(cperl-array-face ((t (:weight normal))))
 '(cperl-hash-face ((t (:weight normal))))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the 'real' perl-mode coloring by overwriting font-lock settings with those of perl-mode.

```
(require 'perl-mode)

(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq font-lock-defaults
                  '((perl-font-lock-keywords perl-font-lock-keywords-1 perl-font-lock-keywords-2)
                    nil nil ((?\_ . "w")) nil
                    (font-lock-syntactic-face-function . perl-font-lock-syntactic-face-function)))
            (font-lock-refresh-defaults)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [color theme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) if you don't like the particular default colors.

Comment: This doesn't help. ColorTheme appears to change all the colors *except* the ones used by cperl-mode, and it doesn't change the colorization of leading glyph, and it doesn't appear to be particularly configurable. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: The problem with cperl-mode appears to be purely limited to arrays and hashes - at least when I tried with Solarize (http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized), that was the only area where colours weren't overridden.