# How can I change the face of scalar variables in emacs cperl-mode?

Tags: perl, emacs, emacs-faces, font-lock

In cperl-mode I am able to change the array and hash faces with `M-x customize-group RET cperl-faces RET`, and change `Cperl Hash Face` and `Cperl Hash Face`. But I can not see any option for changing the scalar variables color.

I have tried to change `font-lock-variable-name-face` both inside the code or from `Cperl Ps Print Face Properties` (where I really want to change the color is in the print) but It does not work. I have tried several cperl-modes from 4.32 to the [rockway-perl6-branch](https://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode/blob/mxd-perl6-merge/cperl-mode.el).

Also I would like not to have the $ colored in the variables, therefore the sigil would stand out better in the printouts (this was asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270772/can-i-use-cperl-mode-with-perl-mode-colorization) but not resolved).

could someone provide me any hints?

Comment: Emacs - when you want to have an excuse to hack on settings, read your e-mail, browse the web, or do fun LISP hacking, instead of actually coding your project :)

Comment: Emacs would be a great OS if only it had a usable text editor. :) (I kid. I love Emacs.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you'd have to modify `cperl-mode` to fontify scalar variables.  It only highlights arrays and hashes.  It doesn't apply *any* face to scalars, except in certain constructs like `my`.

Comment: Well, this is where I headed for, but I didn't find a trivial place to patch. My hope was that  options like `Highlight Variables Indiscriminately` are working on scalar variables: `Currently only changes how scalar variables are highlighted. Note that that variable is only read at initialization time for the variable `perl-font-lock-keywords-2'`. But I don't know which part of cperl-mode should I modify.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but as I searched for this too I want to post my solution:
either run `M-x` `customoize-group` and set `cperl-highlight-variables-indiscriminately` to t or just edit your `.emacs` manually.